# Time function not working

Tags: javascript, html, time

HTML code:

```
<body class="body" onload="buttonFunction(this)">
    <form>
        <p align="center"><strong>You have been on this page for </strong><input title="time spent on webpage" type="text" size="9" name="timespent"></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

JS code:

```
function buttonFunction() {
    startday = new Date();
    clockstart = startday.getTime();
    initstopwatch();
    getSecs();
}


function initstopwatch() {
    var mytime = new Date();
    var timeNow = mytime.getTime();
    var timediff = timeNow - clockstart;
    this.diffsecs = timediff/1000;
    return(this.diffsecs);
}

function getSecs() {
    var mySecs = initstopwatch();
    var mySecs1 = ""+mySecs;
    mySecs1= mySecs1.substring(0,mySecs1.indexOf("."))+ " secs. ";
    document.forms[0].timespent.value = mySecs1;
    window.setTimeout('getSecs()',1000);
}
```

Now, this function is supposed to count the number of seconds a user is on my web page and input that variable into the input box. However, it appears to do nothing. So what is the problem with this function?

Comment: Your `clockstart` variable should be global. You call the `initstopwatch` 2 times in a row. Your code throws `SyntaxError` because you have an invalide `;` here : `window.setTimeout('getSecs()',1000; )`.

Comment: I have corrected that.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos I am trying to make the buttonfunction() sort of a global function, to which any function can go, get whatever input data it needs, and then continue running. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, I posted you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, lets start from the begining, because I will be able to explain more things in this way.

First we need to save the time the user arrived on the page.
We can do this by saving the Date after the page loaded.

```
// The variable is outside because we need every function to
// be able to access it (like a global variable)
var userArrived;

// The function to initialize the counter
function initCounter(){
    // Get the date when the user arrived
    // here we do not use `var` because the variable exists
    userArrived = new Date().getTime(); // This returns the date in milliseconds
}

// Wait the page to load    
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    // Initialize the counter
    initCounter();
}, false);
```

Now we need a function to give us the difference

```
function getCounterValue(){
    // Calculate difference
    var value = new Date().getTime() - userArrived;
    // This variable now have the time the user
    // is on the page in milliseconds

    // Now we need to return the value to the caller
    return value;
}
```

Now that we can get the milliseconds we need a function to parse them to a human readable format.

```
function parseMs2Sec(ms){
    // We calculate seconds using seconds = milliseconds / 1000
    // but we round it so that we don't have decimals
    var sec = Math.round(ms/1000);
    // Now we need to return the value to the caller
    return sec;
}
```

The only thing left to do now it to update any visual element we need every 1 sec (or more).

```
// Save the element on a variable for easy access
var timeSpent = document.forms[0].timespent;

// Update the screen with the latest time
function updateScreeenCounter(){
    // Get the time the user is in the page
    var ms = getCounterValue();
    // Convert it to seconds
    var sec = parseMs2Sec(ms);

    // Display it in the page
    timeSpent.value = sec + " sec."; 
}

// Every 1000 milliseconds
setInterval(function(){
    // Run function
    updateScreeenCounter();
}, 1000);
// But this last code (with the interval)
// needs to run after the counter was initialized
// so we should put it inside the onload event we created.
```

And here is the hole code in a demo :

```js
    //
    // The variable is outside because we need every function to
    // be able to access it (like a global variable)
    var userArrived;

    // The function to initialize the counter
    function initCounter(){
        // Get the date when the user arrived
        // here we do not use `var` because the variable exists
        userArrived = new Date().getTime(); // This returns the date in milliseconds
    }

    // Gives back the time since the user arrived on page (in ms)
    function getCounterValue(){
        // Calculate difference
        var value = new Date().getTime() - userArrived;
        // This variable now have the time the user
        // is on the page in milliseconds
        
        // Now we need to return the value to the caller
        return value;
    }

    // Converts the given ms in the closest seconds
    function parseMs2Sec(ms){
        // We calculate seconds using seconds = milliseconds / 1000
        // but we round it so that we don't have decimals
        var sec = Math.round(ms/1000);
        // Now we need to return the value to the caller
        return sec;
    }

    // Update the screen with the latest time
    function updateScreeenCounter(){
        // Get the time the user is in the page
        var ms = getCounterValue();
        // Convert it to seconds
        var sec = parseMs2Sec(ms);
        
        // Display it in the page
        document.forms[0].timespent.value = sec + " sec."; 
    }

    // Wait the page to load    
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        // Initialize the counter
        initCounter();
        // Every 1000 milliseconds
     setInterval(function(){
         // Run function
         updateScreeenCounter();
     }, 1000);
    }, false);
```

```html
<form>
    <input name="timespent" value="Loading ..."/>
</form>
```

Some more tips :

1. Read again the Javascript tutorial here [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)
2. Read the Chrome DevTools guide here [DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) (Firefox and Opera has the same functionality too)

*~~~ Edit ~~~*

I forgot to mention that it is better to use `setInterval` in this case because it is more accurate than recursive `setTimeout` in a slow computer.

Answer (score 1):

Per Thanasis Grammatopoulos' comment, my previous answer (below) was wrong. I tried running your code by fixing the semicolon positioining, and it runs in Safari.

```
window.setTimeout('getSecs()',1000; )
```

should be

```
window.setTimeout('getSecs()',1000);
```

**my previous incorrect answer**:
setTimeout is only going to call getSecs() once. I think you want to call it once per second, rather than once *in* one second, in which case  you should use:

```
window.setInterval(getSecs,1000);
```

If you want to stop the interval later on (probably a good idea), you can just do:

```
var interval = window.setInterval(getSecs,1000);
```

and later on when you wish to stop the timer, simply call:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: Ah, true. Guess it's just the syntax error then: window.setTimeout('getSecs()',1000; ) instead of window.setTimeout('getSecs()',1000);

Comment: `clockstart` variable is null inside the `initstopwatch`;

Comment: I am trying to make the buttonfunction() sort of a global function, to which any function can go, get whatever input data it needs, and then continue running. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `setTimeout` should be replaced with `setInterval` (as you want `getSecs` to be called repeatedly not just once). Then, what you are expected to pass to it, is reference to the function rather than its invocation, so `getSecs` (no quotes or parentheses) rather than `"getSecs()"`. And that's most probably the cause. I am not able to test the code now. The problem though is that `getSecs()` should not call itself as it will be up to `setInterval`

Secondly, the code deserves a huge cleanup but I will be able to offer more help tomorrow if no one has come up with a nice refactor.

Comment: I am using webstorm, so refactoring should be easy. If I know what to do with the feature.